# SQL Server: Round Date Up

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to round a datetime value up to the nearest full day.

```
UPDATE [DB].[dbo].[TABLE]
-- I'm unsure how to take the DepartureDate and round it up
SET DepartureDate = DepartureDate + ??
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, DepartureDate) = 23
```

The `DepartureDate` is a `datetime` column.

So `2017-11-10 23:00:00.0000` becomes `2017:11:11 00:00:00.0000`

Comment: How does 11:00 PM on 11/10 become midnight? Where does the extra hour of the day go? What does the passenger do when their flight left an hour earlier?

Comment: What do you want a time of 1 am to do? round down to the midnight an hour ago, or round up to the midnight in 23 hours time?

Comment: There won' be a time of 1am, because the query checks if the hour is 23. I'm just wanting to fix up a bunch of results in the database. But to answer your question, yes, 1am would round down. Thakns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DepartureDate, 
       CASE WHEN DepartureDate = CONVERT(DATE, DepartureDate) 
            THEN DepartureDate 
            ELSE CONVERT(DATE,DepartureDate + 1)
       END RoundedDate
FROM YourTable;
```

This will round up `DepartureDate` to the next day, unless the `DepartureDate` is at exactly midnight already.  It is leveraging the fact that a `date` type has a default time of midnight.

The update will simply be:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET DepartureDate = CASE WHEN DepartureDate = CONVERT(DATE, DepartureDate) 
                         THEN DepartureDate 
                         ELSE CONVERT(DATE,DepartureDate + 1)
                    END;
```

**Edit** Since it was clarified in comments that you only want to do this for hour = 23, then just do this:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET DepartureDate = CONVERT(DATE,DepartureDate +1)
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, DepartureDate) = 23
```

Comment: And this is why I don't like writing UPDATE queries for other people; your query has no WHERE clause and will ruin many other dates in his table that he doesn't want changed if he just runs it blindly.. Take care with other people's data

Answer (score 1):

Run this, to check the behviour rounds as you want, then apply to your query:

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(CAST(getutcdate() as FLOAT),0) as datetime)
```

Recommend you SELECT your data with old date and new date, and eyeball it first to check.. Before you update

Comment: I'm wanting to run over a set of results and fix up the dates. I don't think your SELECT statement will work because it doesn't reference a column. Unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: I haven't written your query for you, I've demonstrated how to cast a datetime to a float, round the float, and cast it back.. I was expecting you to take that and apply it to your query.. i.e. `SET DepartureDate = CAST(ROUND(CAST(DepartureDate  as FLOAT),0) as datetime)`. I don't always like writing UPDATE straight into an answer, because people could just copy, paste, run, and then complain their data is screwed for some reason. By making you a) run it, b) apply it, c) check it, it can avoid shafting a live system!

Comment: @AaronDietz check the comments under the question, i have clarified this already

Answer (score 0):

You are right in where clause, if u can use this script to add date

```
select DATEADD(DD, 1,DepartureDate )
```

--Update

```
UPDATE [DB].[dbo].[TABLE]
SET DepartureDate = DATEADD(DD, 1,DepartureDate )
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, DepartureDate) = 23
```